# Square root of continued fraction

Tags: arithmetic, radicals, continued-fractions

Assuming I've been given a number in the form of a continued fraction. Is there a general way to write the square root of that number as continued question?

For example, consider
$$1+\sqrt{2} = 2+\frac1{2+\frac1{2+\frac1{2+\dots}}} = [2;2,2,2,2,2,\dots]$$
Its square root has, according to Mathematica, the form
$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}} = [1; 1, 1, 4, 6, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, \dots]$$
I don't see a pattern here. Is there one?

Comment: There is no known pattern.   If you find one, you will be famous!

Answer (score 0):

According wise words of Alan Baker, the continued fractions algorithm establishes a bijective correspondence between irrational numbers $\theta$ and infinite sets of positive integers $n_0, n_1,n_2....$.

Hence for all sequence $\mathcal S$ of positive integers with no apparent pattern, there is a irrational $\theta$ whose expansion in continued fractions is $\mathcal S$. It could be maybe the case, I mean no apparent pattern, for $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$. How do you know whether or not there is a viewable pattern?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Note that the question is in the first paragraph; there's a reason the second paragraph begins with "For example".

Comment: I understand and  your question it seems to me plausible, I like it. However $ 1+\sqrt 2$ and 
$\sqrt{1+\sqrt 2}$ are quite different numbers. More, a rational $r$ has a finite continued fraction but $\sqrt r$ has an infinite one in general.

Comment: I think you have to change "question" by "fraction".

Answer (score 0):

There will be no 'non-generalized' continued fraction with a repetitive pattern.
These will always lead to values of the form $\frac{P+\sqrt{D}}{Q}$.
There could be a generalized one though, having a repetitive or otherwise clear pattern. Generalized meaning that not only the $a_j$ can be any natural number from 1, but also the quotient part added to it may have a numerator unequal to 1.
See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction for generalized continued fractions for $\pi$ having a regular pattern.